# Seeing the parameter values in each iteration of a loop

Tags: r

I am using RStudio, I have a programm and I want to see the value of each parameter in each iteration. I am seeing only value of parameters on the last iteration.

Here is my R code:

```
k<-read.csv("D:\\Testc.csv")[,1:5]
window<-64
stelle<-""
spalte<-1
co<-0
r<-1
l<-(2/sqrt(window))
while(spalte < 3)
{
  datalist<-matrix(k[,spalte])

  while(r+window<=length(datalist[,1]))
  {
    m<-acf(as.numeric(datalist[r:(r+window),1]),lag.max=32,plot=FALSE)$acf[-1]
    for(i in (1:32))
    {
      if(m[i]>l)
      {
        co<-co+1
      }
    }

    if(co>5)
    {

      row<-as.character(r)
      spalte<-as.character(spalte)
      pos<-rbind(row,spalte)
      stelle<-c(stelle,"-",pos)
    }
    r<-r+30
    co<-0
  } 
  spalte<-spalte+1
}
stelle
```

I want to see the value of `co` ,`spalte`, `stelle` on each iteration. On the left side of RStudio on Workspace tab I see values only for last iteration.

Comment: without a reproducible example, I'm not going to spend too much time dissecting your code, but it looks like you're simply overwriting those values at each iteration...instead of doing that, you could initialize a vector with something like this `vector(mode = "numeric", length = 50)`, and then store values with indexing...something like `spalte[i] <- foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the following code into your loop at the end:

```
print(paste("co=", co))
print(paste("spalte=", spalte))
print(paste("stelle=", stelle))
```